# Overloaded [] operator and referring to the object itself

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I need to refer to each vertex in a method inside the body of class. I've tried using `this->`, `Solid::` etc. but that didn't come up well either.

Anyway I've got everything other overloaded but I can't figure it out nor search it anywhere in the net.

```
#define VERTICES_NR 8

class Solid {
protected:
  Vector _vertices[VERTICES_NR];

// ... some other code (does not matter) ... //


public:
  void Solid::Move()
  {
    Vector temp; // <- my own standalone type.

    cout << "How would you like to move the solid. Type like \"x y z\"" << endl;
    cin >> temp;

    for(int i = 0; i <= VERTICES_NR; i++)
      this->[i] = this->[i] + temp;
  }
}
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Where is your `operator[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write simply

```
  for(int i = 0; i < VERTICES_NR; i++)
                  ^^^
    _vertices[i] += temp;
```

If you want to define the subscript operator then it can look like

```
Vector & operator []( int n )
{
    return  _vertices[i];
}

const Vector & operator []( int n ) const
{
    return  _vertices[i];
}
```

In this case within the class definition you can use it either like

```
operator[]( i )
```

or

```
this->operator[]( i )
```

or

```
( *this )[i]
```

Answer (score 4):

Either call the operator directly:

```
operator[](i) += temp;
```

Or via `this`:

```
(*this)[i] += temp;
```

Comment: In the name of generality, I would add that this applies to all operators that are called on `this`.

Answer (score 1):

The overloaded operator function can be called explicitly by its name, like this:

```
operator[](i) = operator[](i) + temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** You are accessing the class object not the member variable vertices_.

**Correction**:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= VERTICES_NR; i++)
  vertices_[i] = vertices_[i] + temp;
```

can be optimised to

```
vertices_[i] += temp;
```

Comment: yup, but I should create another overload (operator +=) for my Vector class, which I will not do because I'm too lazy :D. Or I'll do it later.